is it possible to achieve a phase margin of \$ 45^\circ \$ while only adjusting \$C_1\$ alone

Schematics above shows a two-stage fully differential amplifier with differential input and output signals. Neglect the body effect and parasitic capacitances of the transistors.
$$
V_{dd} = 3.3\,\text{V}
$$
$$
\mu_n C_{ox} = 134\,\mu \text{A}/\text{V}^2, \quad \mu_p C_{ox} = 45\,\mu \text{A}/\text{V}^2
$$
$$
\lambda_n = 0.1\,\text{V}^{-1}, \quad \lambda_p = 0.2\,\text{V}^{-1}
$$
$$
I_1 = 0.45\,\text{mA}, \quad I_2 = 0.6\,\text{mA}
$$
$$
L = 0.35\,\mu\text{m}
$$
$$
W_1 = W_2 = 50\,\mu\text{m}, \quad W_3 = W_4 = 50\,\mu\text{m}
$$
$$
W_5 = W_6 = 70\,\mu\text{m}, \quad W_7 = W_8 = 60\,\mu\text{m}
$$
$$
C_2 = 1.35\,\text{pF}
$$
Assume the two-stage amplifier in unity gain feedback configuration. Determine the value of \$C_1\$ to obtain a phase margin of \$45^\circ\$. Assume that the unity gain frequency is 400 MHz.
(b): Phase Margin and Feedback Configuration
Determine the value of \$ C_1 \$ to achieve a phase margin (\$ PM \$) of \$ 45^\circ \$ for the two-stage amplifier in a unity-gain feedback configuration, given that the unity-gain frequency (\$ \omega_t \$) is 400 MHz.
Given:

Unity-gain frequency: \$ f_t = 400\,\text{MHz} \$
$$ \omega_t = 2\pi f_t = 2\pi \times 400 \times 10^6\,\text{rad/s} = 2.513 \times 10^9\,\text{rad/s} $$

Total DC gain: $$ A_v = 736 $$ (from Part (a))


Understanding Phase Margin in Two-Pole Amplifiers:
In a two-pole system, the open-loop gain is given by:
$$
A(s) = \frac{A_v}{(1 + s/\omega_{p1})(1 + s/\omega_{p2})}
$$
In unity-gain feedback configuration, the loop gain $$ T(s) $$ is:
$$
T(s) = A(s)
$$
Phase Margin (\$ PM \$) Calculation:
The phase margin is:
$$
PM = 180^\circ - \angle T(j\omega_t) = 180^\circ - \left[ \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\omega_t}{\omega_{p1}} \right) + \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\omega_t}{\omega_{p2}} \right) \right]
$$
Calculating the Poles:

First Pole (\$ \omega_{p1} \$) at the Output of the First Stage:

$$
\omega_{p1} = \frac{1}{R_{o1} C_1}
$$

Second Pole (\$ \omega_{p2} \$) at the Output of the Second Stage:

$$
\omega_{p2} = \frac{1}{R_{o2} C_2}
$$
From Part (a):

$$ R_{o1} = 14.815\,\text{k}\Omega $$
$$ R_{o2} = 5.555\,\text{k}\Omega $$
$$ C_2 = 1.35\,\text{pF} $$

Calculate \$ \omega_{p2} \$:
$$
\omega_{p2} = \frac{1}{R_{o2} C_2} = \frac{1}{5.555 \times 10^3\,\Omega \times 1.35 \times 10^{-12}\,\text{F}} = \frac{1}{7.5 \times 10^{-9}\,\text{s}} = 133.33 \times 10^6\,\text{rad/s}
$$
Convert \$ \omega_{p2} \$ to frequency:
$$
f_{p2} = \frac{\omega_{p2}}{2\pi} = \frac{133.33 \times 10^6}{2\pi} \approx 21.22\,\text{MHz}
$$
Assessing the Phase Margin with Given \$ \omega_t \$:
Given that \$ \omega_t = 2.513 \times 10^9\,\text{rad/s} \$, we can calculate:

Phase Shift Due to the First Pole:

Since \$ \omega_t \gg \omega_{p1} \$ (because \$ A_v \$ is large):
$$
\frac{\omega_t}{\omega_{p1}} = A_v = 736
$$
Thus:
$$
\theta_1 = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\omega_t}{\omega_{p1}} \right) \approx \tan^{-1}(736) \approx 89.92^\circ
$$

Phase Shift Due to the Second Pole:

$$
\frac{\omega_t}{\omega_{p2}} = \frac{2.513 \times 10^9}{133.33 \times 10^6} \approx 18.85
$$
$$
\theta_2 = \tan^{-1}(18.85) \approx 86.97^\circ
$$

Total Phase Shift and Phase Margin:

$$
\angle T(j\omega_t) = \theta_1 + \theta_2 \approx 89.92^\circ + 86.97^\circ \approx 176.89^\circ
$$
$$
PM = 180^\circ - \angle T(j\omega_t) = 180^\circ - 176.89^\circ \approx 3.11^\circ
$$

Desired Phase Shift from Second Pole:

$$
PM = 180^\circ - [ \tan^{-1}(A_v) + \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\omega_t}{\omega_{p2}} \right) ] = 45^\circ
$$
Given that $$ \tan^{-1}(A_v) \approx 90^\circ $$, we have:
$$
45^\circ = 180^\circ - 90^\circ - \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\omega_t}{\omega_{p2}} \right)
$$
$$
\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\omega_t}{\omega_{p2}} \right) = 45^\circ
$$
$$
\frac{\omega_t}{\omega_{p2}} = \tan(45^\circ) = 1
$$
Thus:
$$
\omega_t = \omega_{p2} = 133.33 \times 10^6\,\text{rad/s}
$$
But this contradicts the given \$ \omega_t = 2.513 \times 10^9\,\text{rad/s} \$.
**Therefore, it's impossible to achieve a phase margin of \$ 45^\circ \$ with \$ \omega_t = 400\,\text{MHz} \$ and \$ C_2 = 1.35\,\text{pF} \$.
Solution: Adjust \$ C_2 \$ to Increase \$ \omega_{p2} \$:
Since \$ C_2 \$ is limiting the phase margin, we need to reduce \$ C_2 \$ to increase \$ \omega_{p2} \$.
Calculating Required \$ \omega_{p2} \$:
Given \$ PM = 45^\circ \$ and \$ \theta_1 \approx 90^\circ \$:
$$
PM = 180^\circ - \theta_1 - \theta_2 = 180^\circ - 90^\circ - \theta_2 = 90^\circ - \theta_2 = 45^\circ
$$
Thus:
$$
\theta_2 = 45^\circ
$$
$$
\frac{\omega_t}{\omega_{p2}} = \tan(\theta_2) = \tan(45^\circ) = 1
$$
So:
$$
\omega_{p2} = \omega_t = 2.513 \times 10^9\,\text{rad/s}
$$
Calculating Required \$ C_2 \$:
\$ \omega_{p2} = \frac{1}{R_{o2} C_2} \$ implies
\$C_2 = \frac{1}{R_{o2}} \$

To get a phase margin of \$ 45^{\circ} \$ in a two-pole system, all you need to do is place the second pole on the gain crossover frequency, \$ \omega_{p_2} = \omega_t \$. Thus, you need to increase \$ C_1 \$ in your case so that \$ A_v\cdot \omega_{p_1}=\omega_{p_2} \$. In other words, following a single-pole approximation until we hit \$ \omega_{p_2} \$, the roll off slope is \$20\,\text{dB/dec}\$. Working back from the gain crossover frequency, you can get the required value of \$ \omega_{p_1} \$ and hence \$ C_1 \$.

But gain also changes when you change $C_1$ since
$$A_v = \frac{\omega_t} {\omega_{p1}}$$
where $\omega_t$ is unity gain. At phase margin of 45 $ \circ$, gain is around 1.11, much  lower than the given DC gain
$A _v \approx 736$

That is when you wish to keep $\omega_t$ constant. I.e. there is no solution for a pre-determined $\omega_t$ and $\omega_{p_2}$ if they already do not overlap. In my solution, $\omega_t$ is fixed at $\omega_{p_2}$ and then $\omega_{p_1}$ is adjusted according to the DC gain of $A_v = 736$.

It looks like you use $$A_v = \frac{\omega_{p1}} {\omega_{p2}} = \frac{\omega_{p1}} {\omega_{t}}$$, however, I think $$A_v = \frac{\omega_{t}} {\omega_{p1}}$$

You are correct and there was a typo in my original answer, corrected now.
